# Import a function from one python file and use that function as a step function in metaflow

Tags: python, netflix-metaflow

I have a function `sayHello` defined in one python file `utils.py`. I also have a python file `flow.py` that runs a simple metaflow. I want to import `sayHello` from `utils.py` and use `sayHello` as a step function in `flow.py`. Is it possible to do that? This might be hard because we need `self` in the class. If it's possible, one question is that we how do pass output from the previous step into the function and pass the output to next step. The following is my attempt.

```
#utils.py
def sayHello():
    print("hello world")
```

---

```
#flow.py
from metaflow import FlowSpec, step, Parameter
from metaflow import Metaflow
from utils import sayHello

def function(p):
    return p

class BranchFlow(FlowSpec):
    @step
    def start(self):
        self.next(self.a, self.b, self.sayHello)

    @step
    def a(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.next(self.join)

    @step
    def b(self):
        self.x = 2
        self.next(self.join)


    @step
    def join(self, inputs):
        print('a is %s' % inputs.a.x)
        print('b is %s' % inputs.b.x)
        print('total is %d' % sum(input.x for input in inputs))
        self.next(self.end)

    @step
    def end(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
     BranchFlow()
```

Comment: "Is it possible to do that?" Yes, almost anything you can think of is possible.

Comment: "This might be hard because we need self in the class." What do you mean?

Comment: "how do pass output from the previous step into the function and pass the output to next step" you probably need to return a value rather than printing it.

Comment: I want to use sayHello function as a step function. The step function always comes with self

Comment: I think you mean that a step function must have `self` as a parameter. This is because as I say in my answer below that the step function must be a method of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `FlowSpec.next()`](https://docs.metaflow.org/api/flowspec#FlowSpec.next), the method you pass to `self.next()` must be a member of the current class and decorated with `@step`.

Probably the easiest way to use another function from another module is to wrap it in a member function:

```
class BranchFlow(FlowSpec):
    # ...

    @step
    def sayHello(self):
        sayHello()
```

Now you can do `self.next(self.sayHello)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the `sayHello` method to reference `self` then add a parameter to the sayHello method if the `utils.py`. I believe you are importing the method correctly, so that looks good. Just change it slightly:

```py
#utils.py
def sayHello(self, ...other_args_if_needed):
    # Assuming `self` has a `getName` getter method.
    print(f"hello world, I am {self.getName()}")
```

Now you can import the `sayHello` method and it can be used in the class object. Just remember you need to have getter and setter methods already defined. `self` might just be an empty dictionary when the class is initialized, so `sayHello` would throw an exception if the `getName` wasn't defined on `self`.